# How do I use a raw volume with a database on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, databases, kubernetes-volume, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to figure out how to launch a web application in a Kubernetes cluster on AWS. Right now I'm not certain about a database. I can see that one can use raw block volumes, which are supposedly faster:

> This mode is useful to provide a Pod the fastest possible way to access a volume, without any filesystem layer between the Pod and the volume.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

And they seem to be recommended particularly for databases:

> There are some specialized applications that require direct access to a block device because, for example, the file system layer introduces unneeded overhead. The most common case is databases, which prefer to organize their data directly on the underlying storage.

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/07/raw-block-volume-support-to-beta/

By databases they supposedly mean PostgreSQL, MariaDB, Redis, whatever.

As such, I wonder if I should use raw block volumes for databases. Because on one hand they recommend it, but I didn't see an example. If so, should I create a custom database image to mount the device into the directory? Interestingly, Kubegres doesn't seem to be using block volumes:

https://github.com/reactive-tech/kubegres/blob/v1.12/controllers/spec/template/yaml/PrimaryStatefulSetTemplate.yaml#L19-L27

My test yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mydeployment
  namespace: myns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: mariadb
        env:
        - name: MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: '1'
        volumeDevices:
        - name: persistent-storage
          devicePath: /dev/xvda
      volumes:
      - name: persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: ebs-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ebs-claim
  namespace: myns
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: gp2
  volumeMode: Block
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Comment: Are you using some Managed Kubernetes Service like EKS? And are you just trying to attach a Disk/SSD as a PVC ? Can you show where is the info where "they recommend it"?

Comment: @KristianKanchev Indeed, I was probably too succinct. See the updated question. I'm using EKS. That's probably the best option on AWS. And I've managed to attach a EBS volume to the container as you can probably see. Not sure if that can be called a disk/SSD. They question is about make a database use the device. And if it's worth it.

Comment: Yes, EBS is an SSD as per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes.html) document. It's good that you are using EKS, for example, we use MongoDB which uses a PVC from a snapshot, so it is totally worth it depending on what you need. I suggest you use the CSI driver for managing your PVC and EBS [CSI driver doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html).

Comment: So for the other question, I suggest you see how to deploy a WordPress app on EKS as it will use the similar setup you are going for with the PVC, then redo it for your app. [Example HowTo](https://avikkundu.medium.com/deploying-wordpress-with-mysql-on-top-of-amazon-eks-27bb99fb088b)

Comment: @KristianKanchev Thanks for the example. I've got to inspect it more closely. But at first glance, it doesn't use raw block volumes :) When I said "worth it," I meant them (raw block volumes). Should I consider that as, "You don't normally need them, particularly with PostgreSQL, MariaDB, ..."? Any advantages of the CSI driver you can name off the top of your head?

Comment: I would read through this => [Link](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/raw-block.html) I have not worked that much with raw block volumes, I directly jumped in with CSI driver, so my opinion will not be valid and will lead to CSI.